# Как сделать отступ внутри border?

Tags: border

[image: border]

Как сделать отступ от border? То есть идет dot затем небольшой отступ и сам border. Как сделать именно этот отступ между dot и border?

Comment: Внутри border - padding, снаружи - margin

Comment: Уже это пробовал.

Comment: покажите код, вам помогут

Comment: Если бы был код, не было бы данного вопроса

Comment: Вопрос без кода противоречит правилам сообщества и должен быть закрыт.

Comment: Вопрос состоит в том, как написать данный код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я делал так.

```css
* {
   background: red;
}
li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 1px;
    text-indent: -999px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 20px;
}
li.active::after {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid red;
    content: " ";
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
    <li class="active"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ol>
```